# SwiftUI Preview of mac device in preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

How can I render the Xcode Preview to a iMac device when I develop a macOS app there is no real device in

```
   struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
           ContentView()
    }
   }
```

All I see is the code I write but I would like to see the whole device before I even write a line code Apple is so inconsistent...

I Run Xcode on MacBook and iMac Pro and would like to see both devices in preview

Any help is highly valued!

Comment: Have you experimented with the previewDevice modifier?

Comment: Hey John thanks I tried them but it seems Mac is not really supported I will try it on iMac maybe the screen is just to small on a MacBook. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
           .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Mac"))
   }
}
```

The list of devices you can specify for that rawValue (as of right now) is:

> - "Mac"
> - "iPhone 7"
> - "iPhone 7 Plus"
> - "iPhone 8"
> - "iPhone 8 Plus"
> - "iPhone SE"
> - "iPhone X"
> - "iPhone Xs"
> - "iPhone Xs Max"
> - "iPhone Xr"
> - "iPad mini 4"
> - "iPad Air 2"
> - "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
> - "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)"
> - "iPad (5th generation)"
> - "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)"
> - "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)"
> - "iPad (6th generation)"
> - "iPad Pro (11-inch)"
> - "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)"
> - "iPad mini (5th generation)"
> - "iPad Air (3rd generation)"
> - "Apple TV"
> - "Apple TV 4K"
> - "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)"
> - "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm"
> - "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm"
> - "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm"
> - "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm"
> - "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm"
> - "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm"

Apple's documentation is a little lackluster on this one, but some of the info for this can be found at this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previewdevice

I paid for a macOS App that does a phenomenal job of sifting through the SwiftUI documentation (waaaaay better than what Apple put out).  It's a little pricey, but if you're interested, it can be found at:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/a-companion-for-swiftui/id1485436674?mt=12